# Questions on vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

> A line $L$ passes through the point with position vector $i-3j+2k$ and is parallel to the line $R=4i-5j+k+\lambda(5i+2k-k)$.
>
> a) Write down a vector equation for $L$.
> b) Hence find the coordinates where $L$ crosses the $xy$ plane.

I suppose $R$ and $L$ have the same direction vector then equation of $L$ is given by
(a) $L=i-3j+2k+\beta(5i+2j-k)$ but how do I do the second (b)

Comment: Hint: What will $\beta$ be when $L$ crosses the plane?

Answer (score 0):

When $L$ crosses the $xy$ plane, the value of $z$ is zero. Hence

$$\begin{align*}
0 = 2 -\beta \implies \beta = 2
\end{align*}$$

Plug this into $L$ to find the coordinates: $11i + j$